# Find duplicate phrases - any tool or regex

Tags: microsoft-word, notepad++, regex

I've got a long document, and I suspect that some phrases (one or multiple sentences) are identical or at least similiar. Is there some way to find these repetitive phrases? Some tool or regex?

Answer (score 0):

Finding **identical** sentences can easily be done in Notepad++:

1. Use a regexp to have every sentence on a new line. This can be done (for example) be searching for all `.` and replacing them with `.\n`
2. Remove all whitespaces at the beginning of the line.
3. Now go ahead and sort the lines (TextFX -> TextFX Tools)
4. Convert the EOL character to UNIX because ot makes things simpler (Edit -> EOL conversion)
5. Now search for duplicated lines by searching for `^([^\n]+)\n\1`

To find similar sentences you would need something like a word-stemming program or some kind of fuzzy-search.

Comment: That will only find two identical lines that are one after the other. Is that what the OP is asking?

Comment: No, it will find all identical lines; this is what step 3. is for. Since we sort the lines, identical lines will be sorted one after the other.