# Removing replies in downloaded emails (i.e., non-consecutive duplicate sentences from txt file)

Tags: email, regex, text-formatting, deduplication, textfiles

Hello Experts and Fellow Learners!

I have dozens of text files that contain monthly archives of a listserv. I'm trying to eliminate/delete quoted replies so that each message only appears once across all files. Most users of the list do not use inline quoting, so that is helpful! I have the Message ID, In-Reply-To, and all header information, yet I know that this is a tricky task.

Complicating matters is the fact that many email clients are used with all their different systems for dealing with replies. So, sometimes the quoted emails come with ">" at the start of the line (which I already learned to remove), some insert paragraph breaks (seemingly randomly?), some use "---Original Message---" or "PersonZ wrote/writes:" and, of course, there is no standard "end" to mark the end of the reply.

I've been searching for a regex solution and testing possibilities for days, and haven't found anything that works without sorting the lines (i.e., the solutions all require consecutive duplicates). Here is one example of a solution that is really close that involves making everything a new line and sorting them - but sorting them defeats the purpose of the project (semantic analysis).

[Find duplicate phrases - any tool or regex](https://superuser.com/questions/737200/find-duplicate-phrases-any-tool-or-regex?newreg=bc6fca52641248e58acf3a873aa26fba)

Here's another solution that is also close, yet it requires searching from the beginning of a line. It doesn't work in my situation because various email clients inserting paragraph breaks in the middle of sentences.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32660532/remove-delete-all-duplicate-lines

I'm in a Win10 x64 desktop environment. I am somewhat new to regex. I've been using simple FNR (Find and Replace from codeplex, GrepWin, and TextCrawler Free), and I am open to other software solutions (or methods). If need be, I can figure out how to run php commands using xammp. In other words, the whole process has been a learning experience, so I'm happy to continue.

EDIT: If you'd like a look at a mock up example - with a mock regex that I know doesn't work and didn't expect to work - look here: https://regex101.com/r/FmAMH5/1

Sorry for the length, but I wanted to provide needed info right away.

Thank you,
Jeremy

Comment: For someone like me that is somewhat familiar with Regex but not an expert, I would need to better understand (or see some better examples) of what you start with "text" file content wise, and what you would like the expected results to appear. So it that means including more than one example of "before" and expected "after" since you have cases that complicate matter worse, then so be it.... I might be able to help or give some starting point suggestion if this part were more clear to me.

Comment: @Spittin'IT Thanks for the request. The file varies incredibly, which is why I tried to give a narrative rundown. I did throw a very, very quick example in my edit on regex101 with a regex that I know doesn't work (and that is not meant as a solution). I just want the repeated text strings identified so I can remove them - how we conceptualize that (whether through header info or thinking about these sentences as non-consecutive repeating strings) depends on what is possible. I can remove the headers and email signatures no problem - I'm now concerned with the quoted replies/repeating content.

Comment: I don't think regex is the right tool for the job here. Sounds like something AWK (in combination with some regex, used inside AWK) would be good at. Still, it's not a simple problem, and the solution will not be a one-liner...

Comment: @Wouter I was looking at awk a few days ago, bit haven't sorted out a solution yet. And you're right, I wouldn't expect a one-liner. I certainly understand the complexity of my question and have devoted around 10 hours so far to trying to figure it out. Still, I'm hopeful.

Comment: @McDonald's Did my example help, or did it just cloud the issue? In any case, thank you.